# Pandas PercentageChange -

Tags: python, pandas

I'm creating a percentage change function with pandas:

```
def percentchange(today, yest, vl):

   r = vl if yest==0 else ((today-yest)/yest)*100
   return r

df['newcol'] = percentchange(df['col2'], df['col1'], -999)
```

To handle div by zero errors, I want to set the column output to 'vl' == -999 if a zero is present.

This gives "ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."

Help appreciated as I'm unsure what to do next after Googling it.

```
         Contract Name         Last Trade Date  Strike  Last Price  col1  col2  Bid-Ask Spread % Volume Open Interest
0   QQQ210920C00270000   2021-09-10 9:54AM EDT   270.0      111.44  0.0  0.0               0.0     10            10
1   QQQ210920C00280000  2021-09-20 12:16AM EDT   280.0       97.66  0.0  0.0               0.0      0             0
2   QQQ210920C00305000  2021-09-20 12:16AM EDT   305.0       69.81  0.0  0.0               0.0      0             0
3   QQQ210920C00310000  2021-09-20 12:16AM EDT   310.0       65.14  0.0  0.0               0.0      0             0
4   QQQ210920C00325000  2021-09-01 10:11AM EDT   325.0       57.44  0.0  0.0               0.0      6             0
```

Comment: Are you trying to calculate the percentage change for each row value? What does your data look like? Your question is unclear

Comment: Yes go through each row and do the change. Dataframe col2 and col1 are type np.float. The dataframe has stock prices in

Comment: You'll need to post your dataframe and post the output of `df.to_dict()` in your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col2' : [4,7,3],
    'col1' : [1,2,0],
})
df['newcol'] = np.where(df['col1']==0, -999, (df['col2']-df['col1'])/df['col1']*100)
```

|  | col2 | col1 | newcol | calculation for understanding |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 4 | 1 | 300 | ( (4-1)/1) *100 |
| 1 | 7 | 2 | 250 | ( (7-2)/2) *100 |
| 2 | 3 | 0 | -999 | col1 is zero |